# How to make git worktrees work with feature/chore/fix convention?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I use the feature/fix/chore convention for structuring my branches on my repos. When trying to use git worktree I have a problem on which if I add a worktree like this:

```
git worktree add feature/feature_1
```

What it will do is create create a new branch called feature_1 and place it under a foler name feature, instead of checking out my already existing remote branch called feature/feature_1.

Then when I try to do a git push I get the following error: "fatal: the current branch feature_1 has no upstream branch".

When I check the mapping of the branches using `git remote show origin` I see the message:

```
Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    feature/feature_1 merges with remote feature/feature_1
```

So, in theory things are set up as expected, but don't work out.

I tried using `git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true` it will create a new feature_1 branch, located outside my feature folder on the remote repo.

Any pointers how I can get this to work?

Comment: "*What it will do is create create a new branch called feature_1 and place it under a foler name feature*" -> yes, that's how slashes in branch names are handled in git, regardless of using additional worktrees. (Your overall problem is another thing, this is just a sidenote)

Comment: I just tried `$ git worktree add -b feature/foo ../otherfolder bar` and it works as intended, the new worktree is in its new folder, checked out on a new branch `feature/foo` pointing to the same commit as branch `bar`. If you omit arguments, git assumes some, did you try to be more explicit in your command?

Comment: Looks like your argument is assumed to be the path of the new worktree, while you expect it to be the new branch name, is it so?

Comment: so if I want to checkout the already existing remote branch "feature/feature_1" I would just need to add it to the worktree as `git worktree add -b feature/feature_1` ? the branch I'm trying to add to my worktree is not already in a worktree, so I'm not sure I follow the second argument `../otherfolder bar`.

Comment: `$ git worktree add -b` will create a new branch, I want to just checkout my already existing remote branch `feature/feature_1` to a worktree.

Comment: just FYI, I also tried the `--guess_remote` flag without success

Comment: *I want to just checkout my already existing remote branch* You cannot check out a remote branch. You must create a local branch that tracks the remote branch, and *then* you can create a worktree for your local branch.

Comment: The argument after `-b` is **not** the branch used as a base, it's meant to be the name of the new branch to create. In `git worktree add [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<commit-ish>]` your `feature/feature_1` is for `<commit-ish>`, not for `<new-branch>`. Most importantly, give `<path>` explicitly.

Comment: then my guess would:
`$ git worktree add -b feature_1 ./feature 88fcb2a4` would create a branch feature_1 unbder the path ./feature and it would point to the same branch as the branch that has commit 88fcb2a4? Or commit-ish can be the branch name?

Comment: Do you really want to use `worktree` sounds like you just want to use `checkout` or `switch`. If you really want a separate worktree you have to put it outside of your current working directory. `git worktree add ../feature/feature_1` then go to that directory `cd ../feature/feature_1` and then switch to your branch `git switch feature/feature_1` that should do the trick.

Comment: My understanding of the concepts is limited. I want to use worktree because is a convenient way of having multiple branches available at the same time without having to commit+squash or stash if I want to jump from one branch to another. I already figured out what works for me: `$ git worktree add feature/feature_1 feature/feature_1` worked as intended for branches already available at the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

Note the usage of `git worktree` :

```
usage: git worktree add [<options>] <path> [<commit-ish>]
```

Without the [<commit-ish>] optional arg, it implies a branch name from what is a path name.

To get what you want, ie avoid the inference of a branch name, you must give both path and commit-ish explicitly:

```
git worktree add feature/feature_1 feature/feature_1
```

In this case, the first `feature/feature_1` is strictly a pathname, not used to derived a branch name, and the second `feature/feature_1` is the branch to be checked out at that path.

In any case, realistically the path name would be something like `~/proj/feature_1`, ie a path outside of the CWD repo, or you'll end up with a worktree-inside-a-worktree, which is not invalid, but might be confusing to yourself, especially because you can end up with **worktree-inside-a-worktree-inside-a-worktree-turtles-all-the-way-down**.